# Add custom properties to MQTT message for sending to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, message, azure-iot-hub, custom-properties

I have sent messages from device to Azure IoT Hub using MQTT client (like mosquitto). But I want to add custom properties to these messages like the standard SDK of Microsoft.

[image: Azure IoT Message custom properties]

Is there any suggestion for that?

**Any idea will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance**

Comment: you can use a *topic* for publishing a custom property, for instance: **devices/mydeviceid/messages/events/compression=gzip&temperatureAlert=true**

Comment: you can use the below code 

# Define the message callback function
def message_callback(message, user_context):
    print("Received message: {}".format(message))
    print("Custom properties: {}".format(message.custom_properties))
    print("Body: {}".format(message.data))

Comment: # Send messages with custom properties
while True:
    # Simulate telemetry values
    temperature = random.uniform(15, 30)
    humidity = random.uniform(20, 80)

    # Build the message with simulated telemetry values
    msg_txt = '{{"temperature": {temperature},"humidity": {humidity}}}'
    message = Message(msg_txt.format(temperature=temperature, humidity=humidity))

    # Add a custom application property to the message
    if temperature > 38:  message.custom_properties["temperatureAlert"] = "true"
    else:  message.custom_properties["temperatureAlert"] = "false"

Comment: # Send the message
    print("Sending message: {}".format(message))
    client.send_message(message)

    # Increment the counter
    counter += 1

Comment: @RomanKiss Thank you. I have tried but it didn't work. Actually I only want to have compression=gzip. Should I format the custom properties to RFC2396 Standard like this document https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/main/doc/edgehub-api.md?

Comment: @RajeshM Thank you but it doesn't help me a lot.

Comment: Hi, I have tried again and the solution of @RomanKiss is correct. Thank you so much again Roman :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be found in

## Sending device-to-cloud messages

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

Thank @Roman for your suggestion